# Removing all files from a just initialized git repo staging area

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I just created a repo

```
git init
```

and then did

```
git add .
```

I then did a

```
git status
```

and noticed that there were there a couple of files I didn't want. I went to `.git/info/` and added those files to the `exclude` file. I then tried to

```
git reset .
```

but got a

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
```

Trying a

```
git reset --hard
```

had the same effect. I guess this is because I still didn't make a commit?  How can I achieve the same effect on a new, comitless repo, then?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Update: the title of your question suggests you want to unstage all files, but from the text of your question, it sounds as if you just want to unstage a couple of them - you've now clarified this below, and I've added a bit to the end of my answer mentioning how to unstage every new file that has just been added.*

You're correct that that error you see is because you haven't created any commits yet.

When you did `git add .` that "staged" everything in the work tree for your next commit.  As well as ignoring those files, you also want to unstage them.  If you type `git status`, it gives you a hint how to do this:

```
 # Changes to be committed:
 #   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
```

... so if the files that you want to unstage are `foo.txt` and `bar.c`, you would do:

```
git rm --cached foo.txt bar.c
```

Then you can carry on and create your first commit with:

```
git commit
```

... as you would expect.

---

You've clarified below that in fact you want to unstage every file you've just added - in that case you can, as [grzuy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721352/removing-all-files-from-a-just-initialized-git-repo-staging-area/5721500#5721500) says, modify that to:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

... and start staging files more selectively with `git add filename`.

Comment: Assuming that your assumptions are correct, could you edit the question title?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My intention was to unstage everything and later manually add just the files that I want.

Answer (score 5):

For all the repo:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```